# Best Practice, how to get info from a reference field in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, api, mongoose

I have a Schema Users that has a field manager of type `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId`that puts the id of a manager from another Schema that has other info about the manager.
When i want to put the manager name in a result of a call to the User Schema i use a for loop as below:

```
const res = await axios.get('/api/users/all');
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    };
    //adding planner name to the data
    for (let element of res.data) {
      element.plannerName = await axios.post(
        '/api/planners/plannerName',
        { id: element.planner },
        config
      );
    }
```

This works but i feel it is a slow solution. I am new to this field and i want to know if this is the best practice to do such task.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called `join` in the database language.

You have to join user collection with manager collection. For doing this you can use `populate()` function after find.

Here is the code:

```js
let users = await User.find({}).populate('manager');
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what i was looking for. I will make sure to read more about pulling better queries using populate and victuals from db rather than run JS scripts in the front end. I think performance much better this way.

Comment: Checkout the `Model.aggregation()` it is a powerful function of `mongodb` and `mongoose`.